# If $m^4 + 4^n$ is a prime, for $n,m\geq2$, then $m$ is odd and $n$ is even?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

One thing which i got is $m^4 + 4^n$ is congruent to $1 \pmod 8$ when both $n,m$ are odd...

Is it an iff condition?

Comment: Please check whether my edit did not unintentionally change the meaning of your question.

Answer (score 3):

$1^4+4^1=5$ is prime, but n is not even.

$m=1$ and $n=6$, $1+4^6=17\times 241,$ so is not prime.

Comment: sorry m not equal to 1

Comment: @user49236 : what about $n=0$?

Comment: @user49236 I just edited the answer.

Comment: $3^4+4^9=5^2\cdot17\cdot617$

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake.

Answer (score 3):

It follows easily  from $$x^4+4y^4=(x^2-2xy+2y^2)(x^2+2 xy+2 y^2) \ .  $$

Comment: If $n=2k+1$ take $x=m$ and $y=2^k$

Answer (score 2):

There are primes when $m=1$ or when $n=0$ (indeed all but one of them are the same).  You are probably excluding them.

For $n=1$ you have $m^4+4^1 = ((m-1)^2 +1) \times ((m+1)^2 +1)$ which is not prime unless $m=1$.

For $n \gt 1$ you have $m^4+4^n \equiv 0 \text{ or } 1 \mod 8$, which leads to your question

Answer (score 0):

If you make some arithmetic modulo $\,4\,$:

$$m^4+4^n=m^4=0,1\pmod 4\Longrightarrow \,\,m\,\,\text{must be odd (why?)}$$

Also, if

$$n=2k+1\Longrightarrow 4^n=4\cdot (4^k)^2\,$$

and Pantelis's answer kicks in.